# How do I prevent this variable being cast from Variable into Tensor after reassigning, in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here's a code snippet that I have. x_hat is cast from tensorflow.python.ops.variables.RefVariable into tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
import tensorflow.contrib.slim.nets as nets
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
image = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((299, 299, 3)))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None])
x_hat = image

print(type(x_hat))
noise = x_hat - x
#filter noise
x_hat = noise + x

print(type(x_hat))
```

Basically, x_hat is modified in a session (code not shown), and after this modification I want to extract "noise" from x_hat, modify "noise", and then add it back to x_hat. However, the code I've written casts x_hat into Tensor, which breaks things later on.

I'm sure my attempt is not the right way of accomplishing what I want, so do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following code is executed with a type change**

```
x_hat = noise + x
```

**The appropriate approach:**

```
op = tf.assign(x_hat,noise+x)
```